# Isomorphism of Algebraic Geometric codes

Tags: coding-theory

Let $\chi/\Bbb F_q$ be an algebraic curve over a finite field $\Bbb F_q$ with $q^s$ rational points for some $s\in(0,1)$. Let $L(D)$ be the riemann roch space with prescribed zeros and poles. Let $P$ and $Q$ be the set of equal number points of cardinality $n\approx O(\log_2^cq)$ on the curve with no point a zero or pole of $L(D)$ with $c>0$. Generate an Algebraic Geometric code by evaluating functions in $L(D)$ over points in $P$ and $Q$. Call the codes $C_P$ and $C_Q$.

When is $C_P\cong C_Q$?

Comment: What is your definition of equivalence/isomorphism of codes? Do you only allow permutations of symbol positions, or do you also allow non-zero multipliers of coordinates?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I would first try a toy example with punctured Reed-Solomon codes, i.e. the case where $\chi$ is the projective line (of genus $0$).